# Click on a button on webpage with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, button

I'm trying to click a button on a webpage with Excel VBA. I already loaded the page, logged in and now I need to click on a button at this point. The problem is the button does not have an id or a name. It only has the class attribute which slightly changes everytime I log in. Here's my VBA code so far:

```
Sub test()

    Dim oIE As Object
    Dim oHDoc As HTMLDocument
    
    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    With oIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate sSiteName
    End With
    
    While oIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
 
    Set oHDoc = oIE.document
    
    With oHDoc
        .getElementById("Ecom_User_ID").Value = "xxx"
        .getElementById("Ecom_Password").Value = "xxx"
        .getElementById("Ecom_Button_Login").Click 
    End With

End Sub
```

Below is the HTML code of the button that I want to click

```
<generic-button class="user-info__btn ttu _ngcontent-jlj-3 _nghost-jlj-9" cssclass="btn-inverse">
   <button type="button" class="_ngcontent-jlj-9 btn-inverse btn btn-primary" tabindex="0">
      <p class="_ngcontent-jlj-9">New message</p>
   </button>
</generic-button>
```

On another login i would get:

```
<generic-button class="user-info__btn ttu _ngcontent-vnl-3 _nghost-vnl-9" cssclass="btn-inverse">
   <button type="button" class="_ngcontent-vnl-9 btn-inverse btn btn-primary" tabindex="0">
      <p class="_ngcontent-vnl-9">New message</p>
   </button>
</generic-button>
```

Is there a way to click the button? Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Try `.getElementsByClassName("_ngcontent-jlj-9")(0).Click`

Comment: This didn't work as "jlj" could be anything each time I log in to the website. However, this gave me an idea to use `.getElementsByTagName("button")(3).Click` , as the button I'm trying to click is the forth element using the button tag on the webpage and it seems to work!

Comment: Gotcha, if it's dynamically generated, try narrowing the search space by looking for a parent element that has an ID if possible.

Answer (score 0):

matyd, try to define an object collection containing all the html button objects, then loop through them by checking whether the right 30 characters of the "class" property of the button object equal "-9 btn-inverse btn btn-primary":

```
Dim objCollection           As Object
Dim objElement              As Object

Set objCollection = oHDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
    
    For Each objElement In objCollection
        
        If Right(objElement.Class, 30) = "-9 btn-inverse btn btn-primary" Then
            'proceed with what you want to do...
            Exit For
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: That seems like a good idea, however the line `If Right(objElement.Class, 30) = "-9 btn-inverse btn btn-primary" Then` throws a run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Can you get the objElement.Class value? If so, asign a string variable and fill it?